# Table Thead Does not match up with TD Cells and Does not respect the table size

Tags: html, css

How can the code below be modified such that the Table THead matches up with the TD's and also respect the size (width) of the table? What is happening now is that the table headers expand beyond the size of the div and the table horizontally accross the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
Table Style
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
table a:link {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:visited {
    color: #999999;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:active,
table a:hover {
    color: #bd5a35;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
table {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    table-layout: fixed;


}
table th {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #ededed;
}   
table tr {
    text-align: center;
}   
table td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fafafa;
        text-align: left;
}   
table tr:hover td {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
table th, table td {
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
#container {
    width : 98.7%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
table tr td:first-child, table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table thead {
    _position: fixed;
    _position: relative;
    _position: absolute;

}

TABLE THEAD TR TH {
    top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    _position:relative;
    _position: absolute;
    _position: fixed;
}

table tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 0;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<table id="data">

    <!-- Table Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File Number</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
            <th>Vital Task</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Table Header -->

    <!-- Table Body -->
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>20%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>23%</td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ABC-123-123456</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="#yep-iit-doesnt-exist">Hyperlink Example</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td><a href="#inexistent-id">Another</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- Table Body -->

</table>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#data tr th" ).resizable({
      handles: 'e'
    });
  });
  </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

ETA http://jsfiddle.net/KrB79/

Answer (score 0):

Fix the container's CSS Coding to:

```
#container {
    width : 98.7%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    position: fixed;
}
```

Problem solved with IE7.